# View Virtual Machine display on the ESXi host monitor

Tags: esxi

I have installed VMware ESXi 5.1.0 on physical box and have connected a monitor to it. Is it possible to view the displays from one of the Virtual Machines created on the ESXi instance on the monitor?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible since ESXi is a bare metal hypervisor without advanced graphics/sound/mouse support.

A lot of effort already goes into making ESXi work with all kinds of RAID hardware. If you add a ton of other drivers you end up with a full blown Linux system so you might as well use your preferred distro and VMware Workstation for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VMDirectPath. Add an ATI Graphic card and do a passthrough in ESXi. If you want to use the guest vm as a workstation, you will need to passthrough the USB for keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

No , it is not designed to work that way. 
You are best served by using either vmware player or vmware workstation alternatively you can get a remote console to the virtual machines running on the ESXI server by using the vsphere client.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Setup a USB passthrough for your VM and attach a 10$ USB to VGA "external graphic card", and you'll get reasonable output. I wouldn't use it for movies or games, but normal office work is possible.